# how to disable run the app by BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android

i want to do a task manager soft,i want to check all apps which used android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED and i want to also disable Auto Startup when the mobile start run. i have no clue,if i need the root permission to finish it any advice may receive

Comment: Nice question +1.And i am also waiting for reply from SO

Comment: Related: [Disable autostart on boot](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209345/218526).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you can not change the `/data/system/packages.xml` file above to remove the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

This is because the android framework, at start-up, parses every apk (i.e. app) manifest file and when it sees the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` permission, it calls the app at that time.

Therefore, modifying the file will have no effect.  I've tried this - believe me.  The only way I know of to remove the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` permission (aside from modifying the andorid framework, recompiling it, and loading it onto your phone) is to manually edit the apk files you want to remove the permission from.

Obviously not for the faint of heart!

Answer (score 5):

To check which applications receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent action you can use android `PackageManager` and `ResolveInfo` class something like,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED);

List<ResolveInfo> listApp = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo res : listApp) {
    Log.e("Camera Application Package Name and Activity Name",res.activityInfo.packageName + " " + res.activityInfo.name));
}
```

But I think **its not possible to change other application's permission** which they are used. So you can't prevent it to start at `BOOT_COMPLETED` time.If you want to this then for this you have to **ROOT permission**.

There is one of application on android market that allow you to do it, for example [LBE Privacy Guard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite)

**UPDATE:**

In android framework structure, in `/data/system/packages.xml` which contains all installed application's information include used permission, (I never try this also don't know whether its worked or not) If you can modify this file then may be you can achieve what you want..
Thanks..

Comment: if i have root permission,how to call command to stop it,and how to get the packages.xml to modify it?

Comment: i have known res.activityInfo.packageName,if i can used root permission to stop it,but which command i can used?

Comment: There is no need to any command. Just get this file remove permission from it and back store to that file, and when you restart device then remove permission will take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find out what the component is (e.g., by looking at the app's manifest), you can disable the component from an adb commandline or a root shell with:  pm disable package.name/component.class.name

The Autostarts app does this.  It has GPL (I think) source code that you can re-use for your app if your app is GPL, too.